# Xamarin DataGrid How To Bind?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagrid, xamarin.ios

I found [this](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid) GitHub post that shows a handy Xamarin DataGrid. However, I want to take it a step further and add a checkbox as the left most column, so that I can then on button click capture all the ID's from the grid that have been selected.

Is this achievable in `Xamarin.Forms` and `C#`?

**edit**
So after much googling I discovered it would be much easier to use a "toggle" and I have this code for my XAML.  My issue is how do I bind my database fields to the binding for the labels?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
         x:Class="Test.Pages.TestApprove" >
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="The users below are Requesting Access:"></Label>
<Grid Padding="5,0" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Switch Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Brown" />
    <Label Text="{Binding fname}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="1" 
           BackgroundColor="Blue" IsEnabled="false"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding lname}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="1" IsEnabled="false"
           FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Purple" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding company}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="1"
           FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Green" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding Phone}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="1"  
           FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Orange" />
</Grid>
<Button Command="{Binding ApproveUserCommand}" Text="Approve User" TextColor="White"
        FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
        BackgroundColor="#088da5" />
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>  
</ContentPage>
```

And of course I want to dynamically generate the number of rows that the select query returns...so if there are 10 users requesting access, I should be 10 rows with each users data. Am I going about this the correct way/. How do I bind the data?

Comment: Achievable?  Sure.  But there isn't currently a built in checkbox control, so you'll have to build/find your own (there are LOTS of examples out there).

Comment: @Jason - thanks for the advice.  I was meaning a built in or all in one control that could achieve my result.  I'll keep the googling going as nothing I have found has been "exactly" what I've been after :D

Comment: or use a commercial grid like Syncfusion, etc

Comment: @Jason - am I in the right direction to use the grid that I linked to and use one of the multiple checkboxes I found googling?  Or is that way off the mark?

Comment: as long as it supports using arbitrary controls within cells, I would think so

Comment: The link you posted looks like a library to install from NuGet. The code you posted uses the default grid layout provided by Xamarin forms. I would suggest installing the package or using the built in listview to achieve what you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xaml:**

```
<ContentPage x:Name="self">
  <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
          <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Authorized" PropertyName="IsAuthorized" Width="100">
            <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
          </dg:DataGridColumn>
          <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="Name" Width="2*"/>
          <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Action" PropertyName="Id" PropertyName="Streak" Width="0.7*" IsSortable="False">
            <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Here is the trick: command binds the ViewModel's method, since we needed the Id, we've added the id as column's binding context -->
                <Button Text="Authorize" Command="{Binding AuthorizeCommand,source={x:Reference self}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
          </dg:DataGridColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
  </dg:DataGrid>
</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class MainViewModel
{

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    AuthorizeCommand = new Command<string>(CmdAuthorize);
  }

  public ICommand AuthorizeCommand{get;set;}
  public List<User> Users{get;set;}

  CmdAuthorize(string id)
  {
    var user = Users.First(x=>x.Id == id);
    user.IsAuthorized = true;
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class User: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  bool _isAuthorized;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public string Name{get;set;}  
  public string Id{get;set;}
  public bool IsAuthorized
  {
    get=>_isAuthorized;
    set
    { 
      _isAuthorized =value;
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(nameof(IsAuthorized));
    }
  }
}
```

ps: Do not forget setting `BindingContext` of the page

```
contentPage.BindingContext= new MainViewModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your source code there is no list to bind. Firstly you need it..
Here is a DataGrid implementation with Xaml, no any nugget or third party app.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPIyzWpkrHU

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [Linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)), we prefer answer that provide at least a solid summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. [More info on link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).