# How To Bind DataGrid in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin-studio

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAiQ2.png)This post that shows a handy Xamarin DataGrid. However, I want to take it a step further and add a checkbox as the left most column, so that I can then on button click capture all the ID's from the grid that have been selected.

Is this achievable in Xamarin.Forms and C#?

So after much googling I discovered it would be much easier to use a "toggle" and I have this code for my XAML. My issue is how do I bind my database fields to the binding for the labels?

In here I attached UI also

```
<dg:DataGrid Padding="10,10" ActiveRowColor="White" HeightRequest="{Binding ConnectionsGridHeight}" ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowHeight="50" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#F2F3F7">
                                <x:Arguments>
                                    <ListViewCachingStrategy>RetainElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
                                </x:Arguments>
                                <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn PropertyName="." Width="140">
                                        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <custom:CheckBox CId="{Binding .}" Title="{Binding Reference}" IsChecked="{Binding .IsChecked}" CheckBoxCommand="{Binding .CheckBoxCommand}" IsInfo="true" IsEnabled="{Binding .CanSelectable}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn >
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Amount(Rs)" PropertyName="." Width="*" >
                                        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Entry FontSize="Small" Keyboard="Numeric" TextColor="#757575" Placeholder="0.00" Text="{Binding .Amount, StringFormat='{0:N}'}" IsEnabled="{Binding .IsAmountEnable}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn>
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Min.Pay(Rs)" PropertyName="MinPay" Width="*">
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn>
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Type" PropertyName="." Width="75" >
                                        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Picker Title="Select" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#757575" SelectedIndex="{Binding .Type}" IsEnabled="{Binding .IsTypeEnable}">
                                                    <Picker.ItemsSource>
                                                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                                                            <x:String>Select</x:String>
                                                            <x:String>Prepaid</x:String>
                                                            <x:String>Postpaid</x:String>
                                                        </x:Array>
                                                    </Picker.ItemsSource>
                                                    <Picker.Effects>
                                                        <effects:DropdownEffect />
                                                    </Picker.Effects>
                                                </Picker>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn>
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="BU" PropertyName="SBU" Width="40" >
                                        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Image HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SBUIcon}}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn>
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="OCS" PropertyName="OCS" Width="40" >
                                        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Image HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DotIcon}}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn>
                                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Switch" PropertyName="Switch" Width="60" >
                                        <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Image HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DotIcon}}" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </dg:DataGridColumn>
                                </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                                    <dg:PaletteCollection>
                                        <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
                                    </dg:PaletteCollection>
                                </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                                <dg:DataGrid.Resources>
                                    <ResourceDictionary>
                                        <converters:SBUIconConverter x:Key="SBUIcon" />
                                        <converters:DotIconConverter x:Key="DotIcon" />
                                    </ResourceDictionary>
                                </dg:DataGrid.Resources>
                            </dg:DataGrid>

                            <custom:CheckBox Margin="10,25,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Title="Reference #" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedAll}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanAllCheckSelectable}" />
```

Comment: This is for mac, ipad something or what?

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta for android tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin DataGrid How To Bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489658/xamarin-datagrid-how-to-bind)